# how to scroll down widget inside column in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll

right now I have column that contains widget like this

```
Positioned(
      top: ..,
      width: ..,
      height: ..,
Column(children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                Container(),
                Container(),
                Container(),
              ]),
        ),
        Column(children: <Widget>[
          my widget
        ]),
        Column(children: <Widget>[
          my widget
        ]),
        Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                ))
      ]
      )),
```

I have tried wraping my Column using LayoutBuilder and SingleChildScrollView, but nothing changed, I still can not scroll down my column, is there another way to scroll down my Column?

Comment: try replacing your column with ListView

Comment: It works well with ListView, thank you for your help :D

Comment: you're welcome ,i posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace column with ListView and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget inside a SingleChildScrollView,like this

```
 Positioned(
      top: ..,
      width: ..,
      height: ..,
SingleChildScrollView(
  child:   Column(children: <Widget>[

          Padding(

            child: Row(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                children: <Widget>[

                  Container(),

                  Container(),

                  Container(),

                  Container(),

                ]),

          ),

          Column(children: <Widget>[

            my widget

          ]),

          Column(children: <Widget>[

            my widget

          ]),

          Container(

              child: new ListView.builder(

                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

                  ))

        ]

        ),
))
```